# C: Recursive function to sum numbers

Tags: c

I need to make a recursive function that sums the odd numbers n. For example, the function receives 5:  1+3+5+7+9 = 25

Comment: Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24469235/edit) your question to English?

Comment: `int sum_odd(int n){ return n < 1 ? 0 : 2*n-1 + sum_odd(n-1); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int recurse(int n)
{
    if(n<=0)     
        return 0;
    else
        return (2*n-1)+recurse(n-1);
}
```